# I wanted to route to another page once redux dispatch will finish in react JS

Tags: reactjs, redux

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onQuestionLoad: payload => {dispatch({ type: FETCH_QUESTION_SET, payload });},
    onLoad: payload =>  dispatch({ type: INSTRUCTION, payload }),
    isShowTimer: payload => dispatch({ type: SHOW_TIMER, payload }),
    setTestStatus: payload => {dispatch({ type: SET_TEST_STATUS, payload });},
    onChange: payload => dispatch({ type: UPDATE_TIME, payload }),
    resetTimer: payload => dispatch({ type: UPDATE_TIME, payload })
});




    const startTest = () => {
        Api.getTestStatus()
            .then(res => {                
                if (res.data.message == "Success") {
                    let userTestId = res.data.data.userTestId;
                    Api.getTestStatusById(userTestId)
                    .then(r => {
                        if(r.data.message === 'Success') {
                            props.setTestStatus(res.data)
                            .then(()=>{
                                history.push('/testpanel');
                            })
                        }
                    })

                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                setIsError(true)
            })
    }
```

I am using function-based component in ReactJS and Redux.
I wanted to execute the **history.push('/testpanel')** just after the finishing of **props.setTestStatus(res.data)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to connect the **testStatus** state from your store to your component, and inside the render function you have to verify if  **testStatus**   is not null then redirect your user to /testpanel.

Note: don't use **history.push('/testpanel')** inside your reducer or action it's not good practice.

Comment: Thanks a lot..!! @Soufiane Boutahlil